# Excel VBA - Loop a specific column in structured table and get corresponding cells values from other columns

Tags: excel, vba

I start using structured table with VBA code, but here I face a problem which I do not manage by myself.
I have a structured table in which I loop through 1 column and need to get values from other columns depending on some criteria:

- if the cells value is "Finished"
- then I take 3 dates (dateScheduled, dateRelease and dateReady) from 3 other columns and perform some calculations and tests based on these dates

the problem is that I can get the values of the date columns (they are well formatted and have values in it), so none of the next actions triggered by the first if is working.

Here is part of the whole code of my macro, I hope this is sufficient to figure out what is wrong.

```
For Each valCell In Range("thisIsMyTable[Task Status]").Cells
    If valCell = "Finished" Then
        dateScheduled = Range("thisIsMyTable[End Date]").Cells
        dateRelease = Range("thisIsMyTable[Release Date]").Cells
        dateReady = Range("thisIsMyTable[Date Ready]").Cells
        totalFinishCat = totalFinishCat + 1
        daysToFinished = daysToFinished + DateDiff("d", dateReady, dateRelease)
        If Range("thisIsMyTable[Time Spent]").Cells = "" Then
            timeTotalFinished = timeTotalFinished + Range("thisIsMyTable[Time estimate]").Cells + Range("thisIsMyTable[Extra hours]").Cells
        Else
            timeTotalFinished = timeTotalFinished + Range("thisIsMyTable[Time Spent]").Cells
        End If
        
        If dateRelease >= dateStartReport Then
            monthFinished = monthFinished + 1
            timeMonthFinished = timeMonthFinished + Range("thisIsMyTable[Time Spent]").Cells
            daysToFinishedMonth = daysToFinishedMonth + DateDiff("d", dateReady, dateRelease)
            If dateRelease > dateScheduled Then
                afterDue = afterDue + 1
                diff = DateDiff("d", dateScheduled, dateRelease)
                afterDay = afterDay + diff
            Else
                beforeDue = beforeDue + 1
                diff = DateDiff("d", dateRelease, dateScheduled)
                beforeDay = beforeDay + diff
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next valCell
```

I have tried out by adding .value or .value2 like so:

```
dateScheduled = Range("thisIsMyTable[End Date]").Cells.value
```

or

```
dateScheduled = Range("thisIsMyTable[End Date]").Cells.value2
```

but it does not work better. I have checked by adding .select like so:

```
dateScheduled = Range("thisIsMyTable[End Date]").Cells.select
```

and this will select the entire column, not the cells as I expect. So it appears that my method to just get the cells value is not appropriate.

Any help is welcome

Comment: `dateScheduled = Range("thisIsMyTable[End Date]").Cells` will results in `dateScheduled` becoming a 2D array containing the values of all the cells in the Range.  You'll need to loop through each cell.  Will be faster if you read the entire table into an array, and then loop through the table.  See the late Chip Pearson's page on [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a lookup of column names to column number, you can loop through the rows of the table and extract the value using Range(1, columnno). For example

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MyMacro()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tb As ListObject
    Dim r As ListRow
    Dim sStatus As String, dEnd As Date, dRelease As Date, dReady As Date

    ' table
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set tb = ws.ListObjects("thisIsMyTable")

     ' lookup column name to number
    Dim dict As Object, c As ListColumn
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  
    For Each c In tb.ListColumns
        dict.Add c.Name, c.Index
    Next

    ' scan table rows
    For Each r In tb.ListRows
        sStatus = r.Range(1, dict("Task Status"))
        If sStatus = "Finished" Then

            dEnd = r.Range(1, dict("End Date"))
            dRelease = r.Range(1, dict("Release Date"))
            dReady = r.Range(1, dict("Date Ready"))

            Debug.Print dEnd, dRelease, dReady
     
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```